# StringFormat doesn't seem to react

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

I have the following binding in my xaml, I can see the double value shown however the `StringFormat` is completely ignored.

```
<Label Content="{Binding ByteCount, StringFormat=n}"/>
```

`ByteCount` property is of type double. I even changed it even to string and it still doesn't work.

What could be the reason please?

Update:

```
public double ByteCount
{
            get
            {
                return CloneHelper.GetSize(this);
            }
}

public static class CloneHelper
    {
        public static double GetSize(BookSetViewModel book)
        {
            .....

            return total;
        }
}
```

Comment: Perhaps you can include the actual binding in your question? (btw: a ByteCount property represented as a double!?)

Comment: If `ByteCount` is an `int`, you might be missing a converter.

Comment: try removing `Mode=TwoWay` first, don't see any sense of it with Label

Comment: Does the output window in Visual Studio report any BindingExpression failures?

Comment: I have added the requested binding. Many Thanks

Comment: No BindingErrors to be seen in output. Its a mystery...

Comment: I noticed that the output window in VS doesn't report binding failures when the binding source is not explicitly mentioned. Can you specify the binding source explicitly (i.e., through ElementName, or whatever)?

Comment: @Willem, I use MVVM. The property above lies on the ViewModel.

Comment: I can only assume that, for whatever reason, the DataContext for the Label is not what you think it is, but why and how is impossible to tell from the snippets provided.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

WPF's `Label` actually has a `ContentStringFormat` property which overwrites whatever the binding's `StringFormat` is

Set `ContentStringFormat` instead

```
<Label Content="{Binding ByteCount}" ContentStringFormat="n" />
```

Comment: You are a star Rachel. Amazing found, this was it!!! :)  Is this the same for silverlight? I need to test this...

Comment: @Kave I'm not sure if it's the same for Silverlight, but I would assume so. Should be easy to write a quick test and find out.

Answer (score 0):

The `StringFormat` property has peculiar syntax which you have to use.

For your example, you should use this snippet.

```
<Label Content="{Binding ByteCount, StringFormat={}{0:n}}" />
```

[Here's](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.bindingbase.stringformat.aspx) a link to the MSDN page for the StringFormat property.

Comment: It works perfectly well without, the {} is just there to escape the curly braces. "StringFormat=n" should work (and works here) too.

Comment: I think you miss a } at the end before ". Nonetheless it doesn't work either. I don't understand...

Answer (score 0):

Have no idea what is the reason, maybe because of target type (for label it is object), but it works ok for the TextBlock:

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding ByteCount, StringFormat=n}"/>
```